# Scipy optimize: error trying to put function to minimize

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

I want to find minimal function value  with `scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar`

**Function:**

```
def error(w0, w1):
    dataset = data
    total_error = 0
    for i in range(1, 25000):
        meta = dataset['Height'][i] - ((w0 + w1 * dataset['Weight'][i]))**2
        total_error = total_error + meta
    return total_error
```

I want `w0 = 50` and `w1 = [-5,5]`
As I'm trying to put function under scipy method I see different errors:

```
res = minimize_scalar(error)
TypeError: error() missing 1 required positional argument: 'w1'
```

```
w0 = 50
w1 = 0
res = minimize_scalar(error (w0, w1))
'numpy.float64' object is not callable
```

```
w0 = 50
w1 = range(-5,5)
res = minimize_scalar(error, w0, w1)
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Comment: what minimal value are you searching for exactly? `w0` or `w1` or both?

Comment: refer to this on how to use [minimize_sclaer](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar.html)

Comment: I trying to find min for "error" with w0 =50 and w1 as variable between -5 to 5

Answer (score 1):

The key to optimization problems is distinguishing your variables and their use. Also, it is wise to refers to the docs and use the correct variable labels when calling the function. Based on the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar.html), this should do the trick:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize_scalar

def error(x, w0):
    dataset = data
    total_error = 0
    for i in range(1, 25000):
        meta = dataset['Height'][i] - ((w0 + x * dataset['Weight'][i]))**2
        total_error = total_error + meta
    return total_error

res = minimize_scalar(fun=error, bounds=(-5, 5), args=(50,))
```

Comment: I got:
invalid value encountered in double_scalars  tmp2 = (x - v) * (fx - fw)

Comment: You must check that you are passing the correct values / types/ formats. The error occurs in the scipy code it seems. Without any clear trace-back or an idea on what you doing I cannot help.